# Получить Cer из X509Certificate2

Tags: c#, certificate

Доброго времени суток.

API (такском) для авторизации просит файл .Cer, тот самый файл который можно экспортировать через свойства обозревателя или через оснастку Сертификаты Крипто ПРО.

```
certificateData = GetCertificateBody(this.CertFile.Text);
var request = CreatePostRequest(string.Format("{0}API/CertificateLogin", url), null, vendorid);
request.ContentType = "application/pkcs7-mime";
request.ContentLength = certificateData.Length;
```

Ну и так далее...

Все прекрасно работает, но нужен сам файл сертификата. Хочу брать сертификат из хранилища. Получаю объект X509Certificate2, но никак не могу понять как из него взять то что лежит в файле .Cer.

```
private static byte[] GetCertificateBody(string fileName)
{
    byte[] certificateData;
    using (var certificateStream = File.OpenRead(fileName))
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        certificateStream.CopyTo(ms);
        ms.Position = 0;
        certificateData = ms.ToArray();
    }
    return certificateData;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В общем все оказалось слишком просто.
certificateData =cert.RawData;
Соответственно чтобы получить файл cer достаточно сделать

```html
Convert.ToBase64String( cert.RawData, Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks);
```

Где Cert это объект X509Certificate2